# Pro Guard obfuscation for subclass

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard

I've tried for obfuscation on my project. I want to obfuscate every code, but `public void onClick(...` is not obfuscate.

### This is my code

```
private void aa(boolean z) {
    if (!z) {
        fv a = new fv.a(this).a();
        a.setTitle("Internet Connection");
        a.setMessage("Koneksi Internet dibutuhkan untuk menggunakan aplikasi ini");
        a.setButton(-2, "Buka pengaturan wifi", new OnClickListener(this) {
            final /* synthetic */ MainActivity a;

            {
                this.a = r1;
            }

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                this.a.startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS"));
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        a.show();
        a.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }
```

can you see there, `public void onClick(...` still like original

---

### This is my proguard

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
-useuniqueclassmembernames

-overloadaggressively
-repackageclasses '~'
-microedition
-dontwarn android.support.**
-printmapping out.map
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
 public static *** d(...);
 public static *** i(...);
 public static *** v(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"onClick()" cannot be renamed because it is the implementation of a system interface class.  If it the name was changed the system would not know what method to call.  You also notice that "startActivity()" and "dismiss()" are also no renamed.

Comment: ok I see, but I've my own function that I was create, and it still not rename (obfuscate).

Comment: You created what is inside that function.  The name "onCreate" was given by the OnClickListener interface definition.